# V-for is re-rendering all the components when a class changes

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, performance, vue.js

I am currently changing classes of images according to their index by moveIndex method and by using key events. I am able to do this smoothly in computers but in case of TVs, it takes too much time to do that. Whenever I work with smaller arrays, process is being done smoothly but in larger arrays, process is taking too much time. Here is a code block that might help you clarify the problem :

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
      <div is="Channel" v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="index" :channel="channel"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import channelz from "../trsubs.channels.json";
import Channel from './Channel';
export default {
  components:{
    Channel
  },
  data() {
    return {
      channels: Object.freeze(channelz.Root.Channels.Channel),
      currentIndex: 1,
      columnNumber: 9,
      rowNumber: 7
    };
  },
    moveIndex(e) {
      var images = document.querySelectorAll("div > div > div > div > img");
      images[this.currentIndex-1]["className"] = "";
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
          this.currentIndex =
            this.currentIndex === 1
              ? this.channels.length - 1
              : this.currentIndex - 1;
          break;
        case 38:
          this.currentIndex =
            this.currentIndex - this.columnNumber > 0
              ? (this.currentIndex -= this.columnNumber) : this.currentIndex
          break;
        case 39:
          this.currentIndex =
            this.currentIndex === this.channels.length - 1
              ? 1
              : this.currentIndex + 1;
          break;
        case 40:
          this.currentIndex =
            this.currentIndex + this.columnNumber < this.channels.length
              ? (this.currentIndex += this.columnNumber)
              : this.currentIndex;
          break;
      }
      images[this.currentIndex-1]["className"] = "selectedIndex";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is my channel component :

```
<template>
  <div v-if="channel.ChName">
          <img :src="'http://uyanik.tv/conf/images/'+channel.Image">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['channel']
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a unique value you already have in your channel collection: ChName seems a good candidate.

```html
<div is="Channel" v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="channel.ChName" :channel="channel"></div>
```

This should help vue understand what have changed and what not, and re-render accordingly.

---

Also, please avoid using vanilla javascript to select element inside vue.

I am referring to:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll("div > div > div > div > img");
```

Which should probably converted to something like:

```js
var images = this.channels.map(ch => ch.Image)
```

Comment: As you can see from my moveIndex method, I am changing classes according to their indexes so mapping channel Image wouldn't work out pretty well.